# ClearContents in multiple columns with condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear content of cells in certain row if value in column A is different than 5. Columns I want to clear are C, D, F, H, J, K, L, M (not all).

I wrote below code and it works, but with bigger sheets it's quite slow and I'm looking for more efficient way for doing this.

```
Sub clear_cont()
 
Dim x, y As Integer
 
 y = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
 For x = 1 To y
 If Cells(x, 1).Value <> 5 Then
 Cells(x, 3).ClearContents
 Cells(x, 4).ClearContents
 Cells(x, 6).ClearContents 
 Cells(x, 8).ClearContents
 Cells(x, 10).ClearContents
 Cells(x, 11).ClearContents
 Cells(x, 12).ClearContents
 Cells(x, 13).ClearContents
 
 End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtering to skip the loop.

```
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim clrrange As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lr, 13))
            .AutoFilter 1, "<>5"
            Set clrrange = Application.Intersect(Union(.Columns(3), .Columns(4), .Columns(6), .Columns(8) _
            .Columns(10), .Columns(11), .Columns(12), .Columns(13)), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            If Not clrrange Is Nothing Then
                clrrange.ClearContents
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you, works way better! But I wonder if I can use this solution if condition will be not value but interior color of cell? For example different than red.

Comment: Yes you can, just need to change the filter value and operator

Comment: Can you help how? <> operator doesn't work, I can't change = to <> in .AutoFIlter Field:=3, Criteria:=RGB(255,0,0), Operator:=x1FilterCellColor

Comment: `.AutoFilter 1, RGB(255, 0, 0), xlFilterCellColor` Something like that.

Comment: 1. "Method autofilter of object range failed". 2. I need filter color different than, not equal to, is that possible using filters?

Comment: its an l (el) not a 1 (one), I think it will depend on specifically what you are trying to do. If filtering not on a color means blank fill then yes, I'm unsure if you can somehow `not` a specific color though.

Comment: Yes, I don't think that possible. From what I read in VBA you can only use filters available in Excel, so you can't exclude specific color (you can by filters by the rest of colors, but you have to know them). Thanks for help anyway.